# Uma Function não reconhece a outra

Tags: angularjs

Estou com problemas em montar um service para angularJS, eu chamo uma função e quando ela chama outra diz que não reconhece como função o que foi chamado

```
Uncaught TypeError: teste.redirect is not a function
```

o código que eu estou usando é esse:

```
teste.service('testService', function () {
this.bla = function (a,b){
    console.log("ta na function do teste"+ a + " | " + b);
    teste.redirect("");
};


this.login = function(pass,user){
    var cPass = Sha256.hash(pass);
    var cUser = user;
    var json = {"user": cUser,"password": cPass};

    console.log(json)
    consumeService (null, JSON.stringify(json), "login", "POST", "alerta", function(result){
        var loginTO = result;
        if(loginTO != null){
            teste.redirect("logon.html");
        }
    }); 
};

this.redirect = function (destiny) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/web/";
    var direct = url + destiny;
    if($scope.validateToken()){ window.location(direct);
    }else{ window.location(url) ; }
};
```

Alguém saberia onde está o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma variável para persistir a referência de escopo da função original:

```
    teste.service('testService', function () {

    var that = this;

    this.bla = function (a,b){
        console.log("ta na function do teste"+ a + " | " + b);
        that.redirect("");
    };


    this.login = function(pass,user){
        var cPass = Sha256.hash(pass);
        var cUser = user;
        var json = {"user": cUser,"password": cPass};

        console.log(json)
        consumeService (null, JSON.stringify(json), "login", "POST", "alerta", function(result){
            var loginTO = result;
            if(loginTO != null){
                that.redirect("logon.html");

        }
    }); 
};

this.redirect = function (destiny) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/web/";
    var direct = url + destiny;
    if($scope.validateToken()){ window.location(direct);
    }else{ window.location(url) ; }
};
```

Comment: funcionou para mim, valeu cara

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual o teu contexto, mais vou lhe dar um conselho. Não sobrecarregue os serviços do angular expondo métodos que serão utilizados somente de forma local. Para tal você pode declarar funções que não serão expostas para cada instancia do serviço. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
teste.service('testService', function () {
    function metodoLocal(param) {
        console.log("Redirect..." + param);
    }

    return {
         metodoExposto: function(){
            metodoLocal("http://...");
         }
     };
});
```

Observe os métodos expostos e os que vão ser usados internamente para gerenciar o serviço.

Sobre a resolução do teu problema. Podes criar uma variável como já citado, ou ainda podes prefixo "this" para referenciar os métodos de instancia.

```
teste.service('testService', function () {
    this.bla = function (a,b){
        teste.redirect("");
    };

    this.login = function(pass,user){
        this.bla("a", "b");
    };
});
```