# Por que função está retornando undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-service, funções

estou tentando obter um json de retorno da função e associalo a uma variavel, pois assim tiro a necessidade de estruturar o dado recebido com pagina de dentro dessa função e consigo trabalhar em outra função isso, porém não está dando certo o retorno está sendo `undefined`, vejam o codigo

```
var token = getCookie("token");
var json = {};
$scope.query = consumeService (token, JSON.stringify(json), "funcionario/getAllFuncionarios", "POST", "alerta", function(result){
    var r = result;
    return r;
});

console.log("Query :" +$scope.query);
```

Comment: Veja se essa resposta te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92779/uma-function-n%C3%A3o-reconhece-a-outra/92781#92781

Comment: tentei aqui e não funcionou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O lucianohdr já cantou a bola. Essa requisição que está tentando fazer é assíncrona. Será preciso usar um método callback para tratar.

```
function chamar(){
    consultar(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
}

function consultar(callback) {
    var token = getCookie("token");
    var json = {};
    consumeService (token, JSON.stringify(json), "funcionario/getAllFuncionarios", "POST", "alerta", function(result){
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Talvez pelo fato de ser uma requisição assíncrona, tenta colocar a variavel do $scope dentro da function:

```
var token = getCookie("token");
var json = {};
consumeService (token, JSON.stringify(json), "funcionario/getAllFuncionarios", "POST", "alerta", function(result){
    var r = result;
    console.log("Result :" + r);
    $scope.query = r;
});
```

Comment: tentei aqui man e não funfou, a resposta no console ainda é undefined

Comment: você precisa ter certeza se esse serviço ('funcionario/getAllFuncionarios') está te retornando algo do servidor. Você pode ver isso no Developer Tools do chrome ou Firebug do Mozilla, ou ainda testando com algum plugin para navegador, como por exemplo, o Postman do chrome. No developer tools do chrome é possível ver na aba Network.

Comment: ele está retornando, já testei, ele retorna um json, mas precisei tirar a logica de dentro do consume service para tratar em outra função